# Load() function in R with an input

Tags: r, character, load

I am using R to create a function that allows me to load specific Rdata.
So I have several different files, each containing a specific Rdata set. For instance, if I want to load the information about the northern line, I would write
`load(“TfL/Line/northern/Arrivals.Rdata")`

And if I want circle line, I would write
`load(“TfL/Line/circle/Arrivals.Rdata")`

The question is, can I write a function that takes the name of the tube line, say `LineName`,as an input, using the load function? I tried

```r
Get_information<- function(LineName==NULL){
load(“TfL/Line/LineName/Arrivals.Rdata")}
```

This doesn’t work. Could someone help me deal with this? Thanks!

Comment: `Get_information <- function(LineName){
    path <- paste0("./TfL/Line/", LineName,"Arrivals",".Rdata)
    load(path)
}` paste0 is probably what you're looking for. This assumes your working directory `getwd()` is one folder before TfL

Comment: Hi hannie, welcome to Stack Overflow, and congratulations on asking your first question!

I've edited your question to include code chunks. I do this using backticks (`), but there are a few different ways, which you can read about here:
https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Another very useful guide is 'How to make a minimal, reproducible example': 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

This question doesn't feature a reproducible example, but it's quite simple so I don't think it needs one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass 'LineName' as a variable. Currently you're just writing "LineName" as a string-literal.

There are a few functions which can do this:

### Paste0

Paste0 combines character vectors (literals or objects) into a single string:

`load(paste0(“TfL/Line/", LineName, "/Arrivals.Rdata"))`

### Glue

Glue is a CRAN package which functions in a similar way to `paste0`, but can be easier to write and read:

```r
#install.packages("glue") #<- run if you don't have glue installed
require("glue") # attach the package so that we can use 'glue'
load(glue("TfL/Line/{LineName}/Arrivals.Rdata"))
```

If run either of those inside your function, it will work as intended.